# GoLand IDE: Debug program initiated by shell script (Kubernetes local cluster)

Tags: debugging, kubernetes, goland

I'm a beginner to Kubernetes, and I tried to understand the source code by debugging from GoLand IDE. Starting a cluster with the provided [hack/local-up-cluster.sh](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/hack/local-up-cluster.sh) script works fine, but I cannot debug in GoLand.

I've tried to edit `Run -> EditConfigurations-> +Shell Script` with the script path as hack/local-up-cluster.sh, the script could run successfully but it won't stop at any break point.

Can someone please help me on how to set the IDE to debug the code initiated by a shell script?

Comment: Kubernetes is an extremely large go project. The shell script you mention is over 1000 lines long and is most likely not the right place to start when trying to debug.

You might be better served picking a smaller component to dig into. Pick specific (smaller) component such as apiserver or scheduler and read docs on how to build/debug from there. I found operators to be a great topic to dig into to get familiar with the k8s golang api

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the IDE to launch the process, then you can use the `Run | Attach to process` feature to attach the IDE debugger to an existing project.

Make sure that the compiled application has the optimizations turned off, if you are using Go 1.10+ the compiler flag is `-gcflags="all=-N -l"`.

Comment: I modified the make in local-cluster-up.sh to contain the flag, but the "Attach to process" only shows the pid of etcd. It couldn't find other process like kube-apiserver ot kubelet.